# Computing $\pi_1(f(\mathbf{S}^1),1)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given a map $f:\mathbf{S}^1 \to \mathbf{S}^1$ such that $f(1)=1$, find $\pi_1(f(\mathbf{S}^1),1)$
By definition $\pi_1(f(\mathbf{S}^1),1)=\{[\alpha]_h: \alpha\in \pi(f(\mathbf{S^1}),1)\}$ and I only know that $\pi_1(\mathbf{S}^1,1)$ is generated by $[\omega_1]_h$, $\omega_1(s)=e^{2 \pi i s}$.
Well, $[f \circ \omega_1]_h \in \pi_1(f(\mathbf{S}^1),1)$ then I have the idea that $\pi_1(f(\mathbf{S}^1),1)$ is generated by $[f \circ \omega_1]_h$.

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the question right? It's not possible to solve currently. Either the answer is $\mathbb Z$ or $0$ depending on wether $f$ is surjective or not.

Comment: An algoritm to solve this problem is: 1) Find $f(\mathbf{S}^1)$ 2) Prove that $\{1\} \subset f(\mathbf{S}^1)\subset \mathbf{S}^1$ 3) Prove that $\pi_1(f(\mathbf{S}^1),1)$ is cyclic

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is surjective then $f(S^1)=S^1$ and thus $\pi_1(f(S^1))=\pi_1(S^1)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand if $f$ is not surjective, then the image $f(S^1)$ is a subset of $S^1\backslash\{p\}$ for some point $p\in S^1$. And the latter space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. And thus $\pi_1(f(S^1))$ has to be trivial, since path connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely intervals and so the path connected component of any point in $f(S^1)$ is an interval. And intervals are contractible.

In particular what I'm saying here is that **any** subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has trivial fundamental group (or any homotopy group), regardless of the choice of base point.

Note that I didn't even assume that $f$ is continuous (you didn't as well, although it might be implicit). If it is then "not surjective" case simplifies since $f(S^1)$ is homeomorphic either to $[0,1]$ or a singleton $\{*\}$ as a compact and path connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$.