# Induced Homomorphism in the unit circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism, fundamental-groups

Let $f:(S^1,1)\to(S^1,1)$ a continuous function.
Then calculate:
$f_{*}(\pi_1(S^1,1))$ and $\pi_1(f(S^1),1)$, where $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ and if $[\alpha]\in\pi(X,x)$ then $f_{*}([\alpha])=[f\circ\alpha]\in\pi_1(X,x)$.

I know that $S^1=\langle[\omega_1]\rangle$ where $\omega_1:[0,1]\to S^1:s\mapsto e^{2\pi is}$ but I don't know how to use this ideas.

Comment: The answer would depend on $f$.  For $\pi_1(f(S^1))$, see [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3921893/).

Comment: What we can say is $f_*([\omega_1])=[f]$.